# how to change basis of polynomial using coordination with respect to basis method

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

suppose you have a vector field of second power polynomials, the the standard basis is $\{1,x,x^2\}$. however there is a method to constract another basis namely $\{1-x,1-x^2\}$.

1- how is it possiple to have 2 basis vectors? when dealing with second power polynomials the minimum vectors we need are 3 to span the space?
2- anyone knows this method?? im sure of the answer but not so sure how to get there.

Comment: The second set does not build a basis of $\mathbb{P}^2$. Any basis of $V$ where $\dim V = n$ must have $n$ vectors.

Comment: Then try to write $P(x)=x^2-3 x+9$ using the second basis

Comment: sorry there was another condition i forgot to mention.
the vector space is defined as follows: 
$$
P=\{ p_{1} \in {\mathbb{P}ol}_{2} ([0,2]\mathbb{R})| p(1)=0\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

oke so i figured out how to. i will post the answer for those who are intrested in learning more about algebra.

a second power polynomial can be written as follows:
$$
p(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c
$$
but the condition is given that $p(1)=0$, so then we get:
$$
a+b+c=0
$$
and now do do a coordinate transformation with respectto the standard basis:
$$
{[p]}_{E}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
now we must find $Nul(A)$ in other words $A{[p]_{E}}=\textbf{0}$.
$$
{[p]}_{E}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-x_{2}-x_{3} \\
x_{2}  \\
x_{3}
\end{bmatrix}=-x_{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} -x_{3}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I hope you see that the last 2 vectors also span the space i.e. they form another basis $\{1-x,1-x^{2}\}$ with $dim(P)=2$!!